# Schedulet не запускает php скрипт

Tags: php

Не понимаю когда скрипт запускаю через браузер то всё работает! А когда чере Schedulet(win) как через cmd! То он не обрабатывает! вот сам скрипт:

$scandir="D:/DATA/";

$searchdir="D:/www/iias_error/oborot/"; 
          set_time_limit(999999999);

$der=date("d");

```
            $dir=@scandir("".$scandir."".$der."/");

                            for($a=2;$a<=count($dir);$a++)
                            {

                              $kick=substr($dir[$a],0,1);

if ($kick == "B")

                                {

                            exec('D:\www\iias_error\arj\arj.exe e '.$scandir.''.$der.'/'.$dir[$a].'');

                                $dur=@scandir("".$searchdir."");                for($r=3,$g=1;$r<=count($dur);$r++,$g++){
```

$name=substr($dur[$r],"1","5");

```
                                                  $mfo=substr($dur[$r],6,9);
                                  $body=str_replace(".","",$mfo);

                                  $dirk=$dir[$a];
                                  $dirk=substr($dirk,0,1);
                                                                                            if($name != NULL && $body != NULL){
                                  $up_date=date('d-m-Y');
                                 $file = "D:/WWW/iias_error/error/err".$up_date.".txt";
                                 $current = "\n ".$name." * ".$body."";
                                                                     file_put_contents($file, $current,FILE_APPEND);
                                   }

                                 @unlink("".$dur[$r]."");

             }

      }
                                   }
```

Comment: Что значит не отрабатывает ? Что Вы ожидали, а что получилось ?

Comment: Он должен открывать Arj-Архив с помощью exe-шника! обрабатывать и заносить в txt файл! Через браузер работает! Может какаето функция не воспринимается?

Comment: arj.exe вызывается ? Просто временно удалите из скрипта все остальное и посмотрите.

Comment: Удалил! также работает с браузером а с планировщиком не хочет! Меняю слэш и так \ и так /! Не получается

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем по теме и т.п. но попробуйте [nncron](http://www.nncron.ru/). Cron под Windows. Лично я поставил когда-то туда своих ботов и года два уже не вспоминаю про них.

Comment: nncron глючит на win server 2003(

Comment: Хм, интересно. Как выражается?
у меня год где-то на XP стояло и года полтора на Win7 64b...

Comment: nncron не запускается!

Comment: дело в том что ошибка точно здесь:
 exec('D:\www\iias_error\arj\arj.exe e '.$scandir.''.$der.'/'.$dir[$a].''); 

даже если пишу в cmd D:\SERVER\PHP\php.exe -f  D:\www\1\index.php
 он не может вот этот exec обработать!

Comment: Я вот так выполняю, без -f

    C:/WebServer/php5.2.10/php.exe C:/vw/cron/arch/arch.php

Не могу пока что найти особенности этого флага

Comment: Вообще, для начала - напишите скрипт который просто создаёт файл, и проверте выполняется ли он? Если да, то надо копать в сторону самого скрипта.

Comment: И кстати, для долгих скриптов, имеет смысл использовать:

    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);

Comment: Да запустил с cmd скрипт для копировании файлов работает! а вот такой не фига :  exec("D:\www\iias_error\arj\arj.exe e D:/DATA/30/B0020047.C4U");